# VBA to export sequential changes to an Excel object

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following Excel table constructed from the highlighted cells:[See Graph Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SZump.jpg)

I found this code to save the graph to a MS Word file:

```
Sub Insert_Table()

    Dim WdObj As Object, fname As String
    fname = Range("j2").Value
    Set WdObj = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    WdObj.Visible = False
    Range("J1:M5").Select
    Selection.Copy 'Your Copy Range
    WdObj.Documents.Add
    WdObj.Selection.PasteSpecial Link:=False, _
    DataType:=wdPasteText, Placement:= _
    wdInLine, DisplayAsIcon:=False
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    If fname <> "" Then 'make sure fname is not blank
    With WdObj
    .ChangeFileOpenDirectory ActiveWorkbook.Path 'save Dir
    .ActiveDocument.SaveAs FileName:=fname & ".doc"
    End With
    Else:
    MsgBox ("File not saved, naming range was botched, guess again.")
    End If
    With WdObj
    .ActiveDocument.Close
    .Quit
    End With
    Set WdObj = Nothing

End Sub
```

That works fine, but I would really like to save the table as an enhanced metafile that can eventually be imported into a Word file. Being far too new to VBA codes, I have no idea yet how to do so.

Also, in the table I'm exporting, I use offset values to populate the table, with the "OffV" value changing the source data by one row for each +1 increment. Having the code also increment the value in the cell by +1 each time a new table is saved that would be ideal. So in summary, I'm looking to:

1. Have the code update the table by automatically increasing the value of the reference cell +1 with each loop.
2. Save the table to an EMF file, or something else compatible with Word.
3. Loop the command until all rows in the source worksheet have been processed (in my case, 103 rows).

Grateful for any and all assistance.

Answer (score 0):

Okay - I found part of the solution with some simple code modification. Now I can generate and save a new table for each row:

```
Sub Insert_Table()

For loop_ctr = 1 To 2
ActiveSheet.Range("I2").Value = loop_ctr
Dim WdObj As Object, fname As String
fname = Range("j2").Value
Set WdObj = CreateObject("Word.Application")
WdObj.Visible = False
Range("J1:M5").Select
Selection.Copy 'Your Copy Range
WdObj.Documents.Add
WdObj.Selection.PasteSpecial Link:=False, _
DataType:=wdPasteText, Placement:= _
wdInLine, DisplayAsIcon:=False
Application.CutCopyMode = False
If fname <> "" Then 'make sure fname is not blank
With WdObj
.ChangeFileOpenDirectory ActiveWorkbook.Path 'save Dir
.ActiveDocument.SaveAs FileName:=fname & ".doc"
End With
Else:
MsgBox ("File not saved, naming range was botched, guess again.")
End If
With WdObj
.ActiveDocument.Close
.Quit
End With
Set WdObj = Nothing
Next loop_ctr

End Sub
```

Next step would be to save a file format other than MS Word. Should mention that cell I2 is the offset counter found directly below the cell labeled "OffV".